# Two print buttons with different css on the same page... Possible?

Tags: php, javascript, css, printing, dreamweaver

I'm working with Dreamweaver, coded in **php**.

On one of my pages, I'm trying to add 2 different `print` `buttons`, each one printing a differrent portion of the webpage. For example, one print button is printing the **first paragraph** and the other `print` button is printing the **second paragraph**.

I did the **print CSS** for both buttons and I linked each to its respective *print CSS*, but the second *print CSS* overrules the first one, and so I end up having two print buttons with the same CSS...

What do I need to do?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: Can one have JS that alters which style sheets  are active tied to the buttons? I have no means to test this here, so don't want to post as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could dynamically change the print CSS based upon which button is clicked with something like this:

Add an id to your stylesheet reference:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="print1.css" id="printCss" media="print">
```

Add an on click event to your button:

```
<input type="button" onclick="swapCss();"/>
```

Dynamically swap the css file:

```
function swapCss() {
    document.getElementById('printCss').href = 'print2.css';
}
```

Comment: Would it be the same if i use, instead of buttons, links?

Comment: Yes, except you would want the link to look something like this (so that it doesn't take the user to a new page): `<a href="#" onclick="swapCss(); return false;">print</a>`.

Comment: Now, would it be completely wrong if i ask you something else, completely different... Since we're talking already maybe you can help me again...

Comment: Do you know anything about php includes? Im trying to add some png images but with the 'swap' function, (an image that when the cursor is on top changes). But everytime i put on the include it shows an error message... I have the images in a different file and i bring it to the web page i want to show it in as php include("_includes/swaplinks.php") which is the path but the error says it doesnt work

Comment: @VLP I certainly don't mind helping you out, but proper ettiquete on Stack Overflow dictates that you should ask a new question if it is unrelated to the current one.  You might want to check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/about).  I will certainly keep an eye out for your new question.  Also, if an answer fixes your issue, it is a good idea to accept it.  That way everyone knows it is resolved.